# Open rss item in webview

Tags: android, rss, android-webview, rss-reader

I'm making android rss reader app that get rss ,parse then show items in listView 
Now with my code when item clicked it opens the default browser show rss

I want to show that in another activity in webview

So how can I do it?

Here is my code

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {     Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(listItems.get(pos).getLink()))  ;

    activity.startActivity(i);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write another activity with webview and pass the url you need to open in the intent data before you start the new activity.

The new activity will read the url from the intent and it should then load it in the webview

What kind of help do you need to get this done ?

Comment: How can I get it using getextra in another activity? And it errors when using putextra in sending onItem method

Comment: Please read: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html